# How to put a TextArea inside a table td?

Tags: html, css, textarea, html-table

I want to place a `textarea` inside table `td`. Unfortunately, it stays single-line.

```
<td align="right" valign="top">Текст акции</td>
<td>
    <input type="textarea" rows="10" cols="45" name="push_title" />
</td>
```

If I set its width and height statically, it resizes, but still stays single-line in the middle of it. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `<textarea>` element instead. As such:

```
<td align="right" valign="top">Текст акции</td>
<td>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
</td>
```

Just to give you an example :

```css
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" cellborder="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Текст акции</td>
        <td>
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @NikitaPronchik The code you have provided in the questions says `<input type="textarea"` and not `<textarea>`.