# How do I make the textbox bigger without changing the font size in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is

```
<table border> 
<td><input type="text" id='w4' style="height:200px;font-size:14pt;"></td>
</table>
```

The problem is the cursor doesn't go to the top, it stays at middle because the border just appear bigger but the textbox size is the same. I need a way to get the cursor to start typing at the top of the box.

I'm still pretty new to html I also want to know how to press enter and it will automatically drop the text cursor down or drop to a whole new different text box at the bottom of the table.

Comment: It sounds like you want a multi-line textbox, use `<textarea>` instead of `<input />`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675114/how-to-put-a-textarea-inside-a-table-td - check this

Answer (score 1):

one option would be to use a text area instead

```html
<table border> 
<td><textarea type="text" id='w4' style="height:200px;font-size:14pt;"></textarea></td>
</table>
```

Comment: It works but I would like the text cursor to drop down to the next td when I press enter. Right now it only drop down a line in the same td.

Comment: @zJqson What do you mean drop down to the next text area? The code that you placed above only contains one input